# "It is" vs. "it was"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, tenses

The recurrent cholangitis happened in the past. But when I am discussing the event now, which of the following should I use?

> - It is the incomplete stone removal that caused the recurrent cholangitis.
> - It was the incomplete stone removal that caused the recurrent cholangitis.

Comment: Why close? Can you say?

Comment: Either form is correct. There's no grammatical compulsion one way or the other. Depends on what you'd like to say and mean. Context!

Comment: Hey! What happened to the "It was I/me" question? My answer looks non sequitur now.

Comment: When talking about the past, use the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically both uses are acceptable. They have slightly different meanings so the correct form to use depends on your context.

If the "incomplete stone removal" can still be considered to be the causative agent for the "recurrent cholangitis" then you should use "It IS".

If however the incomplete stone removal stopped being the reason for the sickness or if perhaps there was some other factor at play then you could use "It WAS".

> Our initial diagnosis indicated that **it was** the incomplete stone removal that caused the recurrent cholangitis. As there was no improvement in the patient's condition after complete removal of the stone residues it became apparent that another factor **was** involved.

Comment: This answer can be improved by citing one or more reliable sources which support it.

Comment: First, etiology does not change, only the **conclusions** about the etiology change. Second, "_another factor was involved_" is ambiguous. Does it mean that _incomplete stone removal_ + _factor 2_ were the causes or that only _factor 2_ was the cause (a new conclusion)?

Answer (score 1):

***It was I who called*** is the formally correct English if you're taking a TOEFL test. If you're talking to someone who's just asked *Who called?*, you'd **say** "***I did***" or "***It was me***", or maybe even "***Yo!***", depending on the context.

Give us a context for this admission and someone will give you a more definitive answer.

Comment: @ Bill Franke: In "It was I who called ", I'm not sure whether "I" should be replaced by "me".  I always thought the in this sentence "I" is the object to the verb "was", and therefore "me" should be used instead.  Was I right?

Comment: Really? Is TOEFL actually that stupid? Nobody ever says "It was I who called" in real English. I had thought better of TOEFL, but I suppose I'm hopelessly optomistic.

Comment: @JohnLawler: You don't know my stepmother (88 years old and a retired English teacher). She says it. Honestly. It's what many a _properly educated_ person would have said 100 years ago. But you're right, almost nobody says that these days. Not even me.

Comment: @Yong: The _be_ verb isn't transitive, it's stative, and **doesn't take an object**. Almost all native speakers of English, educated or not, will say "_It was me_", but if you look at 19th-century and early 20th-century grammar books, you'll see that the prescriptive rule was to say "_It was I_". Click on this link: [link](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/grammar-linking-verbs.aspx) and read all about it. Check it on the Net: Type _it was i or it was me_ in a search engine window and you'll find lots of pages that say the same thing.

Comment: In the 19th century, saying it that way was a mark of education -- one had studied Latin and understood its grammar. In the 21st, however,  saying it that way is simply a mark of being old, inflexible, or poorly educated.

Comment: My stepmother is old and inflexible, but not poorly educated. Like most old folks, though, she's convinced that what she knows is right and best and certainly better than what everyone else knows. Holding on for dear life to old forms is surely a hallmark of reactionary or retrograde values, I agree. But this is true for all ultra-orthodox ideologues: **intransigence** (read as the **principled behavior** of the **holier than thou** crowd).